# Check if an BST is a subtree of another bigger BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

This is a question on my assignment: write a program in java, given 2 binary search tree, a big one and a small one, how do you check if the small one is a subtree of the bigger one ?

Comment: Where are you stuck? (what have you tried so far?)

Comment: I try to check for the first match on the small tree's root, then a use dfs to iterate and check, but it seems very complex and time complexity is huge, any better ways to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the root of the small tree in the large tree.
2. Write a recursive function to compare two binary trees, and use it on the small tree and the subtree found in step 1.